# Refreshing Captcha on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, captcha

I have the following code with which I used to refresh a captcha image via JavaScript. Is there anyway I can also achieve that using an AJAX request?

```
<script>
function refreshCaptcha() {
    $("#captcha_code").attr('src','captcha_code.php');
}

</script>

<button name="submit" onClick="refreshCaptcha();">Refresh Captcha</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.post('captcha_code.php', function(data) {
                $('#captcha_code').html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Sachila, Your Script is not working. below  is how the captcha is  outputed in an image tag. <img id="captcha_code" src="captcha_code.php" />

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but then you need to handle session manually!

```
 <script>
 $(".RefreshCaptcha").click(function () {
     $.post('captcha_code.php', function(data, status){
         $("#captcha_code").attr('src', data);
         console.log("ajax log: " +  status);
     });         
 });
</script>
<button class="RefreshCaptcha">Refresh Captcha</button>
```

[w3shcools ajax.post](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

Comment: Your Script is not working. below  is how the captcha is  outputed in an image tag. <img id="captcha_code" src="captcha_code.php" />

Answer (score 0):

Yes AJAX can be used to update the update the image via Javascript. Because the code already uses jQuery, a simple way would be to use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to post to the PHP script. Presuming that *captach_code.php* merely returns the image source (e.g. base-64 encoded string), you can set the *src* attribute to the *response* value (e.g. in the function *updateImage()* below).

```
function refreshCaptcha() {
    $.post('captcha_code.php', updateImage);
}
function updateImage(response) {
      $("#captcha_code").attr('src',response);
}
```

See it in action in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v1sk-j7e9). **Note** - there is no control of the filenames so PHP_SELF is used instead of *captcha_code.php*.

[$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), which implements the Promise interface. Because of this, [.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and other similar functions can be used instead of specifying the success callback:

```
function refreshCaptcha() {
    $.post('captcha_code.php')
    .done(function(response) {
          $("#captcha_code").attr('src',response);
     })
     .fail(function() {
         //fail handler...
     })
     .always(function() {
         //handler for all cases
     });
}
```

See it in action in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p67t-gry5).